# create alarm in android using phonegap and localnotification plugin

Tags: android, cordova, alarm

I'm using phonegap for creating android apps. I created successfully a notification on the android's notification bar with the plugin localnotification here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

Now I want to create a alarm (a kind of seeting alarm in clock), I see some .java file in this plugin has the titles with [alarm...], I think I can do something with this plugin. But I cannot find the examples for this.

Please give me some examples for this kind.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on google, I see that phonegap doesnot support for notification/alarm. And the plugin [localnotification] for android just supports for showing the notification on notification bar. That's it.

Maybe to show an alarm, we need to write an other plugin with some java codes, and using the tutorial how to create a plugin with phonegap at here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android